# Where can I find some "hello world"-simple Beautiful Soup examples?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'd like to do a very simple replacement using Beautiful Soup. Let's say I want to visit all A tags in a page and append "?foo" to their href. Can someone post or link to an example of how to do something simple like that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('''
<html>
   <head><title>Testing</title></head>
   <body>
     <a href="http://foo.com/">foo</a>
     <a href="http://bar.com/bar">Bar</a>
   </body>
</html>''')

for link in soup.findAll('a'): # find all links
    link['href'] = link['href'] + '?foo'

print soup
```

That prints:

```
<html>
<head><title>Testing</title></head>
<body>
<a href="http://foo.com/?foo">foo</a>
<a href="http://bar.com/bar?foo">Bar</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) also has some [examples for changing attributes](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Changing%20attribute%20values). It is an extensive tutorial that covers all common aspects of BeautifulSoup. I don't know what is missing from the documentation, maybe you should clarify.

Answer (score 0):

my example:

```
HEADERS = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5",
       "Accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
       "Accept-Language" : "ru,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3",
       "Accept-Charset" : "windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
       "Accept-Encoding" : "identity, *;q=0",
       "Connection" : "Keep-Alive"}
PROXY=None
timeout=60


def parse_manuf_page_about(page_str_about):
slovar={}
global timeout
socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
if PROXY is not None:
        proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler( { "http": "http://"+PROXY+"/" } )
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
page_request = urllib2.Request(url=page_str_about, headers=HEADERS)
try:
    #print "Page reading ... %s" %page_str
    page_zapr = urllib2.urlopen(url=page_request)
    page=page_zapr.read()
except Exception ,error:
    print str(error)
    res=False
    return res,slovar
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
select_pod=soup.findAll('div', {"class":"win aboutUs"})

promeg= select_pod[0].findAll("p")[0]
zerro_br= promeg.findAll(text=True)
Company_Info=" ".join(zerro_br).strip(" \t\n")
select =soup.findAll('div', {"class":"win"})
cells_tabl= select[0].findAll("tr")

for yach in cells_tabl:
    text_zag=yach.findAll("th")
    for zn_yach in text_zag:
        if len(zn_yach)>0:
            txt_zn_yach="".join(zn_yach.findAll(text=True)).strip(" \t\n")
        else:
            txt_zn_yach= zn_yach.contents[0].strip(" \t\n")
            #print txt_zn_yach
    text_znach_td=yach.findAll("td")
    for zn_yach_td in text_znach_td:
        if len(zn_yach_td)>0:
            txt_zn_yach_td="".join(zn_yach_td.findAll(text=True)).strip(" \t\n")
        else:
            txt_zn_yach_td= zn_yach.contents[0].strip(" \t\n")
            #print txt_zn_yach_td
    # Делаем замены неугодных символов / Replase browsers char
    if "&nbsp" in txt_zn_yach_td:
        while txt_zn_yach_td.find("nbsp;")>0:
            pos_gavna=txt_zn_yach_td.find("&nbsp;")
            txt_zn_yach_td=txt_zn_yach_td[:pos_gavna]+txt_zn_yach_td[pos_gavna+6:]
    if "&quot" in txt_zn_yach_td:
        while txt_zn_yach_td.find("quot;")>0:
            pos_gavna=txt_zn_yach_td.find("&quot;")
            txt_zn_yach_td=txt_zn_yach_td[:pos_gavna]+'"'+txt_zn_yach_td[pos_gavna+6:]
    if "&amp;" in txt_zn_yach_td:
        while txt_zn_yach_td.find("&amp;")>0:
            pos_gavna=txt_zn_yach_td.find("&amp;")
            txt_zn_yach_td=txt_zn_yach_td[:pos_gavna]+'&'+txt_zn_yach_td[pos_gavna+6:]
    slovar[str(txt_zn_yach)]=txt_zn_yach_td
    slovar["Company_Info"]=Company_Info
# разбираем нижнюю таблицу с контактом и вытаскиваем оттуда имя контакта | get name contacts
select_contact=soup.findAll('a', {"class":"member-name"})
for contact_person in select_contact:
    slovar["Contact_Person"]= contact_person.contents[0]
# получаем статус голд партнера по наличию таблички в левом верхнем углу | get Gold status
select_gold_part=soup.findAll('a', {"class":"memberLogo"})
if len(select_gold_part)==0:
    slovar["Gold member"]="N"
else:
    slovar["Gold member"]="Y"
res=True
return res,slovar
```

This code parsing one page of manufactury on Alibaba.com. You can see it page - http://xmxinhuafeng.en.alibaba.com/aboutus.html