# What tools/libraries to write a crawler

Tags: http, language-agnostic, web-crawler

I need a tool that

1. logs in a website (inserting name and password in a form)
2. once logged in downloads a few HTML pages I need

Such tool will need to run on Linux, and it would be great if such tool looks like a common browser to HTTP server.

What tools/libraries could I use?

Comment: It sounds like `wget` will already do what you need, and no new tool is needed.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: as answered to @John K, I think that `wget` is too low level. I'd like something that gives me some more abstraction (eg: the ability to find and fill forms or to automatically keeps session cookies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're familiar with Python then [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) is available. 
There is a learning curve involved because it's a full crawling and screen scraping framework.
It should be capable of doing what you require. Here is a documentation link for [simulating user logins](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-userlogin). It also supports user-agent spoofing so it can appear to be a browser. One thing it will have trouble with is interacting with dynamic content (i.e. JavaScript).

If you want something really simple try [scrape](http://zesty.ca/scrape/). I've used it on a few projects and it's been able to do the job. It's more of a scraper so you'd have to add the crawling logic yourself.

Comment: Hum, it looks really nice... I'm experimenting with (and I'm already kind of stuck: it when I run a script similar to the one you linked, the `after_login` function doesn't seem to get called).

Comment: I added another suggestion to try out that's simpler. Not sure what's wrong. Are you able to trace the HTTP requests/responses to see what's happening under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

[Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) supports authentication and most other web-enabling technologies. Because the software works on the Console you can wrap it (input/output) using your language of choice.

You can also use it as a utility, as is, without any additional programming, to get the few pages you said you need. For example [the docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) show the command the line options `--http-user=user` and  `--http-password=password` to authenticate on an HTTP server.

In fact the website states:

> It is a non-interactive commandline
>   tool, so it may easily be called from
>   scripts, cron jobs, terminals without
>   X-Windows support, etc.

It's available to run on [most platforms](http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions?action=show&redirect=Faq#download).

Comment: `wget` doesn't seem that good for my job (I think! Correct me if I'm wrong): it won't fill forms for me (I'll need to pass the form fields and action as parameters) and will need to manually get cookies from it, and pass back to it in order to keep the session alive...

Comment: You're correct - It supports cookie management through `--cookies`, `--load-cookies`and `--save-cookies`. \ When you manually fill in a form and click Submit, the form data is sent via HTTP POST or GET using name=value pairs representing the form fields - the same can be automated - in wget you submit the same kinds of pairs to the form action url.

Comment: To facilitate the process of knowing what the form submission actually do on HTTP, you would use a web debug tool like Fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ to view the form submissions you make manually and then reconstruct those same calls programatically using wGet (or tool of choice).

Answer (score 0):

A well known tool is BeautifulSoup (in Python).
An example here :
 http://lethain.com/entry/2008/aug/10/an-introduction-to-compassionate-screenscraping/
and here :
[Where can I find some "hello world"-simple Beautiful Soup examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821173/where-can-i-find-some-hello-world-simple-beautiful-soup-examples)

Comment: The other python library that has been suggested (scrapy) looks a little simpler, so I'll first try to use that one. I'll check out beautiful soup later or if I fail with scrapy.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote mine using [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). Its nice and simple, and even has built-in support for following robots.txt, which I find important for crawlers.

Here  is how you'd extract links:

```
b = mechanize.Browser()
b.open('some-url')
links = b.links()
```

Of course, you'd have to write the code for the actual crawling, and also handle the depth of recursion.